# error when deploying to Jenkins * from Css Minimizer version: "15.2-15.3"

Tags: jenkins, production

Error when in `scss` when deployed in Jenkins

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/x/src/app/dashboards/components/health-widget/health-widget.component.scss
- Error: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/x/src/app/dashboards/components/health-widget/health-widget.component.scss from Css Minimizer Error: Transform failed with 1 error: error: Invalid version: "15.2-15.3"
    at failureErrorWithLog (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/x/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1493:15)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Ops-Unified-UI_Ops-UI_PR-519/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1282:29
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Ops-Unified-UI_Ops-UI_PR-519/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:629:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/x/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:726:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Ops-Unified-UI_Ops-UI_PR-519/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:596:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
```

Changing the `minify` property inside the optimization object within `angular.json` to `false` worked; looking for the clean solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this lines in .browserslistrc file
**not ios_saf 15.2-15.3
not safari 15.2-15.3**
and it works good